# What is the Type 1 error for the following test?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

For testing the hypotheses H0: P = 0.8 versus H1: P ≠ 0.8 at 1% significance level, we
obtain a sample of n = 100 and p = 0.75.

Options:

A. 0.100

B. 0.140

C. 0.212  (Correct answer)

D. 0.010

E. 0.020

So far I have,

z= (P^-P)/std dev

= -1.25

za/2 = 2.575

Don't reject null

But I don't know how to get the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test statistic is $$Z \mid H_0 = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)/n}} = \frac{0.75 - 0.8}{\sqrt{0.8 (0.2)/100}} = -1.25.$$  This is approximately standard normally distributed, hence the two-sided $p$-value is $$\Pr[|Z| > 1.25 \mid H_0] \approx 0.2113.$$  The discrepancy may be due to the answer choice (C) being derived from a normal distribution table with limited decimal precision, whereas my value is generated from a computer.

That said, the Type I error of the test remains $\alpha = 0.01$.  This is because the $p$-value that was obtained would lead us to conclude *not* to reject the null.  The $p$-value is *not* the same thing as the Type I error of the test.  To understand the difference, the $p$-value *would* be the Type I error probability *if* the conclusion were to always reject $H_0$.  So, taking the $p$-value we calculated above, what that means is if we decided to conclude $p \ne 0.8$ based on the observed data, the probability that this is an error is about $0.2113$.  But because $\alpha = 0.01$ is already set, the conclusion is that you would not reject and that the sample furnishes insufficient evidence to suggest the true proportion is not $0.8$.  The Type I error is *controlled* at $0.01$ and in fact there is no point in computing the $p$-value of the test in order to know that the Type I error is $0.01$, because you don't need to actually perform the test in order to control this error probability through setting the significance level of the test.

---

In another vein, the test statistic we used above is only an approximation; specifically, it is the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.  The exact $p$-value corresponds to a binomial probability.  If $n = 100$ and the observed proportion is $\hat p = 0.75$, this means there were $X = 75$ "successes" observed.  Under the null hypothesis, $$X \mid H_0 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 100, p_0 = 0.8).$$  Due to the discrete nature of the test statistic, the actual Type I error will be less than the nominal level of the test $\alpha$, and  is computed by first finding a rejection region $\mathcal R_\alpha = [0, l] \cup [u, n]$ with $l$ as large as possible and $u$ as small as possible such that $\Pr[X \ge u \mid H_0] \le 0.005$ and $\Pr[X \le l \mid H_0] \le 0.005$.  The bounds $l, u$ could be found empirically by computer, but a good approach is to use the normal approximation to find initial guesses.  Since the critical value for a standard normal distribution at the $99.5^{\rm th}$ percentile is $z^*_{\alpha/2} = 2.57583$, we compute $$np_0 \pm z^*_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{np_0(1-p_0)} \approx (69.6859, 90.3141).$$  This suggests that we should guess $l \approx 70$ and $u \approx 90$.  Now using a computer, we find $$\sum_{x=0}^{70} \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] \approx 0.011249, \quad \sum_{x=90}^{100} \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] \approx 0.00569638.$$  The lower limit is too big and the upper limit is just a hair too small, so we decrement our guess for $l$ until we obtain $l = 68$, and increment our guess for $u$ until we get $u = 91$:  $$\sum_{x=0}^{68} \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] \approx 0.0031297, \quad \sum_{x=91}^{100} \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] \approx 0.00233356.$$  Hence our rejection region is $$\mathcal R_\alpha = [0, 68] \cup [91, 100].$$  Then the actual Type I error is the sum of these probabilities, $0.00546326 < 0.01$.  Notice how we did not actually need to perform the hypothesis test or compute a $p$-value.

That said, the $p$-value corresponds to computing $$\Pr[X \le 75 \mid H_0] + \Pr[X \ge x' \mid H_0],$$ where $x'$ is the smallest integer above $80$ such that $\Pr[X = x'] \le \Pr[X = 75] \approx 0.0438778$.  Using a computer, this gives us $x' = 86$, hence the two-sided $p$-value is $$\sum_{x = 0}^{75} \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] + \sum_{x=86}^{100} \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] \approx 0.211797.$$  This agrees very closely with our normal approximation.

Comment: +1 for correctness

Comment: You computed the probability of a type I error if alpha refers to the binomial distribution. Like, if we were to ignore the normal approximation, I.e. the actual type I error under the binomial distribution. Since we are “using the normal approximation” maybe there is no need to “adjust the initial guesses.” That would be the actual probability of a type I error under the normal approximation and boundary should be 69 and 91. Catch my drift

Comment: @Stacker The reduction in the size of the test when using a discrete-valued test statistic is due to the inability to "spend" the full, nominal $\alpha$.  The implicit assumption here is that we want the spending to be not more than $\alpha/2 = 0.005$ in each tail, although this means the test is overly conservative compared to a case where we might allow *one* tail to exceed $\alpha/2$.  But this poses problems for justifying which side of the hypothesis should be relaxed.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of a type I error is the probability of rejecting the null when it's true, also known as a false positive. It's the alpha level of your test. So it's 1%, D is the answer. It is alpha because when the null is true, there's alpha percent chance that the sample is as extreme as the point that you're going to reject...which happens to be when you reject.

Comment: Interesting... are there any reasons why my prof said that C is the correct answer? any mistake he made along the way?

Comment: He must’ve made a mistake when making the slides. C could be the result of some related calculation, or just a random number. It’s not possible for the teacher to not understand the concept...unless he doesn’t.

Comment: Actually you got the answer wrong, it actually is 0.212

Comment: you got p value and signifance level mixed up

Comment: no? the type I error is simply alpha